# Migration patch from NServiceBus 2.6 to NServiceBus 3.0

Tags: nservicebus

I have an existing NServiceBus 2.6 application that I want to start moving to 3.0.  I'm looking for the minimum change upgrade in the first instance.  Is this as simple as replace the 2.6 DLLs with the 3.0 Nuget packages or are there other considerations?

Comment: Update - this post from Andreas is worth noting: http://www.nservicebus.com/MigratingToNServiceBus3.0Timeouts.aspx

Comment: Update - new link
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/migrating-to-nservicebus-3.0-timeouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part the application migration is quite straight forward, but depending on your configuration and environment, you may need to make the following changes:

- The new convention over configuration for endpoints may mean you will need to rename your endpoints to match your queue names (@andreasohlund has a good [post](http://andreasohlund.net/2012/01/27/convention-over-configuration-in-nservicebus-3-0/) about this).
- persistence of saga, timeouts, subscriptions etc. now defaults to RavenDb, so if you use SQL Server to persist data, you need to make sure you have to correct profile and endpoint configuration. For SQL Server storage, make sure you add a reference to NServiceBus.NHibernate as it is no longer part of the core.
- Error queues are now referenced differently using different configuration ie. use MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig instead of the regular MsmqTransportConfig error property. You should still be able to use it, but it will look for the MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig first.

Other than that, I don't think you need to do anything else to get you upgrade working. I modified some of my message definitions to take advantage of the new ICommand and IEvent interfaces as a way communicatinf intent more clearly.

Anyway, I'm sure there will be some cases that are specific to your environment that will require different changes but I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks setphenl, the configuration-over-convention changes are a good heads-up.