# What are the incompatibilities between NServiceBus versions 2.5 and 4

Tags: nservicebus

I have heard many people say the two are incompatible however I have not seen any clear details as to what these incompatibilities are. Specifically I would like to know:

- What would prevent me from migrating an existing 2.5 endpoint to the latest 4.x version directly without first moving to a 3.x endpoint.
- Is there anything I should be aware of when creating a new 4.x endpoint considering it will need to communicate with a 2.5 endpoint.  The new endpoint will need to both consume 2.5 messages\events and produce 2.5 compatible messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you migrating directly from V2.x to V4.x, however, it may make the process a lot harder. The default support is for one version backward compatibility, so you will have to test message version support in your context.

Here are some notes:

## Upgrading 2.x to 3.x

NOTE: You will need to do this in 2 steps: 1st step: 2.6 to 3.3.8 (latest 3.x) 2nd step: V 3.x to v 4.x

Upgrading 2.x to 3.x notes

You might want to look at moving to unobtrusive mode in your upgrade for reduced coupling in your code.
The format of saga persistence changes in SQL server for enumerated types, under V2 they were stored by “name” and under V3 the value (i.e. 1,2,3,4) of the enumeration is stored in the database table.
Timeouts migration is described here :http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/migrating-to-nservicebus-3.0-timeouts
The DI abstraction in V2 would inject into a property declared “public static”, but under V3 it won’t inject into a static property. If you’ve got static properties that are “working” under V2, they will be null under V3 until you make them not static.
Upgrading 2.x to 3.x links:

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/releases/tag/3.3.8 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH0qeienRpg http://andreasohlund.net/2012/01/27/convention-over-configuration-in-nservicebus-3-0/ http://andreasohlund.net/2012/03/08/nservicebus-3-0/ [Migration patch from NServiceBus 2.6 to NServiceBus 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445915/migration-patch-from-nservicebus-2-6-to-nservicebus-3-0)

## Upgrading 3.x to 4.x it should be relatively straight forward.

If you are using nuget

For each NServiceBus package, in the nuget management console type

update-package NServiceBus -vresion 4.

Prerequisite: NServiceBus V4.0 requires RavenDB 2.0.0.2261 or later

NServiceBus V4.0 requires the latest RavenDB v2.x to be installed on the same machine.

### Namespace changes to Types and Interfaces

INeedInitialization

Prior to NServicebus 4.0, The interface INeedInitialization was defined in NServiceBus.Config. In NServicebus 4.0, it is defined at the higher namespace level, i.e NServiceBus. If you receive the following compiler error, please remove the using reference to NServiceBus.Config and resolve using NServiceBus: error CS0104:

'INeedInitialization' is an ambiguous reference between 'NServiceBus.INeedInitialization' and 'NServiceBus.Config.INeedInitialization'
Working with Error and Audit queues

The Management Service (now called ServiceConbtrol) (installed with NServiceBus V4.0) consumes the messages from the defined MSMQ Error and Audit queues. While the Management Service is running, you can view the the Error messages by viewing the Error.log queue, and auditing data can be viewed using ServiceInsight.

### Autosubscriptions

Only messages marked as events (IEvent or DefiningEventsAs()) will be auto-subscribed.

Default transaction isolation level

The default transaction isolation level is now ReadCommitted. To revert to Serializable, use this code:

Configure.Transactions.Advanced(settings => 
   settings.IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.Serializable));
SecondLevelRetries: The type SecondLevelRetries (used in the NServiceBus.Management.Retries namespace to configure the retry and the timeout policy) has been moved to the NServiceBus.Features namespace. While version 3.3.x had a separate policy for managing second level retries and timeouts, this has been merged into the new RetryPolicy in NServiceBus 4.0 and it is capable of achieving both functions.

## Breaking changes

PowerShell cmdlets

NServiceBus.Host no longer supports /installinfrastructure. Use PowerShell cmdlets instead. PowerShell cmdlets have been renamed so that they do not clash with any existing cmdlets.

NServiceBus.WebService:

Exposing an endpoint as a WebService using NServiceBus.Webservice has been deprecated in 4.0. Use the WcfService option instead. For example:

YourWcfService : WcfService
TransactionalTransport

The type TransactionalTransport, which used to be defined in the namespace NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional has been renamed to TransportReceiver and moved to the namespace NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport. If you receive the following compiler error, resolve using the new namespace specified above.

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TransactionalTransport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
New Transports Support and Configuration

These new transport samples were added to the NServiceBus samples, illustrating how to configure the new transports:

Messaging.ActiveMQ
Messaging.RabbitMQ
Messaging.SqlServer
Messaging.MSMQ
New configuration APIs

To simplify the transports configuration and make it consistent across all transports. In your config file, specify a connection string, like this:

You then have two options to specify the transport: Specify it as part of the IConfigureThisEndpoint class declaration, e.g.:

public class  EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, 
       UsingTransport
Or specify it in the IWantCustomInitialization.Init method,

public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, 
IWantCustomInitialization
{
   public void Init(){
      Configure.With().DefaultBuilder()
         .UseTransport()
   }
}
New NuGet packages for the new transports

These NuGet packages are also available:

NServiceBus.SqlServer
NServiceBus.ActiveMQ
NServiceBus.RabbitMQ
Example of how to install the NServiceBus.ActiveMQ package

PM> Install-Package NServiceBus.ActiveMQ
New Transport DLLs

Add a reference to the new transport DLLs (in the Binaries directory):

NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ.dll
NServiceBus.Transports.SQlServer.dll
NServiceBus.Transports.ActiveMQ.dll
MSMQ is currently in NServiceBus.Core.dll and does not require any additional reference. NuGet adds the reference automatically.

## Configuration Changes

XmlMessageSerializer

Now supports not wrapping messages in a element for single messages. This makes interoperability with other systems easier. To turn on this feature:

.XmlSerializer( dontWrapSingleMessages: true )
MsmqTransportConfig

The MsmqTransportConfig section has been deprecated in favour of TransportConfig section, like this:

INeedToInstallSomething

The INeedToInstallSomething interface is now resolved via the container.

NHibernate Configuration

NHibernate settings have been simplified, as follows:

Performance Counters

New throughput performance counters and updated performance counters are available:

NServiceBus license installed per machine

Licenses can now be installed in HKLM, allowing you to install one license per server instead of installing a license per endpoint or per Windows account.

LicenseInstaller.exe C:\License.xml
Powershell cmdlet Updates

NServiceBus PowerShell cmdlets have moved to NServiceBus.PowerShell.dll. To import it, run this:

PM> Import-Module .\NServiceBus.PowerShell.dll
NServiceBus Powershell cmdlets have been renamed so they do not clash with any existing cmdlets:

Installs a NServiceBus license file. Install-NServiceBusLicense
Displays all messages in a queue. Get-NServiceBusMSMQMessage
Displays the NServiceBus installed version. Get-NServiceBusVersion
Installs DTC on the machine. Install-NServiceBusDTC
Installs RavenDB on the machine. Install-NServiceBusRavenDB
Installs NServiceBus performance counters on the machine. Install-NServiceBusPerformanceCounters
Installs MSMQ on the machine. Install-NServiceBusMSMQ
Validates if DTC is installed and running on the machine. Test-NServiceBusDTCInstallation
Ensures RavenDB is on the machine. Test-NServiceBusRavenDBInstallation
Validates that NServiceBus performance counters are correctly installed on the machine. Test-NServiceBusPerformanceCountersInstallation
Validates MSMQ is correctly installed on the machine. Test-NServiceBusMSMQInstallation
Adds the required configuration section to the config file. Add-NServiceBusMessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig
Shows the default error and audit queues. Get-NServiceBusLocalMachineSettings
Allows specifying the default error and audit queues. Set-NServiceBusLocalMachineSettings
NServiceBus.Host no longer supports /installinfrastructure. Use PowerShell cmdlets instead.
New Endpoint Configuration API

Sample usage:

Configure.Endpoint.AsSendOnly()
   .Advanced(settings => settings.DisableDurableMessages());
Configure.Transactions.Enable() 
   .Advanced(settings => settings.IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.Serializable)
   .DefaultTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40)) 
   .DisableDistributedTransactions()); 
Embedded RavenDB

RavenDB is not ilmerged anymore. It is embedded instead, using https://github.com/Fody/Costura#readme. The embedding enables client updates (but may require binding redirects). It also allows passing your own DocumentStore, thereby providing full configuration flexibility. Audit and Error Queue Defaults
Server defaults for audit and error queues can now be specified in the registry (see new PowerShell cmdlet Get/Set-NServiceBusLocalMachineSettings, above).

For more details look at release notes(https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/releases/tag/4.0.0)

===============

HTH